# Exclude elements with certain attribute value from xsl:number

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm using `<xsl:number>` to count `<proceduralStep>`. (I'm using Antenna House 6.2)

```
<xsl:number count="proceduralStep" from="content" level="multiple" format="1.1.1.1.1"/>
```

But I want to exclude any proceduralStep that has a parent or child with attribute `@changeType='delete'`

The XML could look like any of these:

```
    <proceduralStep><para>Install This.</para></proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep><para changeMark="1" changeType="delete">Delete this line.</para></proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep><para>Continue with ths</para></proceduralStep>

    <proceduralStep><para><changeInline  changeMark="1" changeType="delete">And this line.</changeInline></para></proceduralStep>

    <proceduralStep><para>Continue with this</para></proceduralStep>
<revst changeMark="1" >
    <proceduralStep><para>Turn the screw....</para></proceduralStep>
    <proceduralStep><para>Hold assembly tool....</para></proceduralStep>
    </revst>
```

And the output should look like this

```
    1.2.11 Install This
           Delete this line
    1.2.12 Continue with ths
```

The other problem is when using `<revst>` as a wrapper for `<proceduralStep>`, the numbering gets restarted:

```
    1.2.13 Continue with this
    1.2.1 Turn the screw....
    1.2.2 Hold assembly tool...
```

instead of:

```
    1.2.13 Continue with this
    1.2.14 Turn the screw....
    1.2.15 Hold assembly tool...
```

`<xsl:number count="ancestor-or-self::*[changeType!='delete']" from="content" level="multiple" format="1.1.1.1.1"/>`

throws the error: Only 'child' and 'attribute' axes are allowed in a match pattern outside predicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to exclude any proceduralStep that has a parent or child
>   with attribute `@changeType='delete'`

To count `proceduralStep` excluding those that have a child node with attribute `@changeType='delete'` use:

```
count="proceduralStep[not(*/@changeType = 'delete')]"
```

---

To extend this to parent nodes too, you can use:

```
count="proceduralStep[not(*/@changeType = 'delete' or parent::*/@changeType = 'delete')]"
```

---

Note that `a!=b` is not the same thing as `not(a=b)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works great. I am not grasping why `a!=b` is not equivalent to `not(a=b)` (I am still having the issue where wrapping `<revst><proceduralStep></proceduralStep></revst>` is restarting the numbering at that level.)

Comment: **1.**  Because `a!=b` will **not** return true when `a` does not exist. **2.** I suspect you want to use `level="any"`. Hard to be sure using your example.

Comment: The `level=multiple` is needed for nested steps, so I will work on that. Too bad, because `level="any"` numbered correctly. You have been really helpful, Michael, I appreciate it!

Comment: This is close `<xsl:number count="revst[not(@changeType = 'delete')] |  proceduralStep[not(*/@changeType = 'delete' or parent::*/@changeType = 'delete')]" from="content" level="multiple" format="1.1.1.1.1"/>` but when `revst` is being used the numbering is 1.14, 1.15.1,1.15.2,1.16 instead of 1.14,1.15,1.16,1.17

Comment: You need to post a reproducible example (including the input and the expected output) - preferably in a new question.

Comment: Thank you [xsl:number question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812752/xslnumber-restarts-when-count-element-is-wrapped-xslt-1-0-xsl-fo)